# partitioning a cloned hard drive which is bigger then the source hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, clone

If I clone my 20 GB hard drive on to a 150GB hard drive using Norton Ghost, what partitioning does the extra 130 GB receive and how can I make use of this extra space if it isn't partitioned?

Comment: Did you check the documentation for Norton Ghost?

Comment: Which version of Norton Ghost?

Answer (score 1):

You can do any of the following:

- Have a destination partition that's identical in size to the original and
  then when in Windows you could partition and format the unused space as an
  additional drive for data, documents etc.
- You could resize the partition as part of the clone process and grow it to use all available space
- Once the new partition has been made, you can then grow it to take up the remaining
  space. I'm not sure if Ghost has a feature to just resize partitions, but you could always use [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php) (it's free) - in fact, Parted Magic can also do the cloning/resizing if you haven't bought Ghost yet ;-)